# "Which can" Vs "Who Can". How to use these in sentences

Tags: word-choice, subcontinental-english

I am learning how to write English.  Can you please tell me which sentence is correct:

> 1)  (name) is the only character **which can** be evolve into three different types.
>
> 2)  (name) is the only character **who can** be evolve into three different types.

"Can be" is correct. Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Who** indicates a  person but **which** indicates animal and  non living things. The second sentence is correct because in the second sentence a person is the subject.

Examples of **who**:

> 1.Then there are the **people who** reason the future will be better.
>
> 2.The English have not understood and cannot understand the self-abnegation of our **Emperor who** wants nothing for himself, but only desires the good of mankind.

Examples of **which**:

> 1. He found a dog **which** was lost.
> 2. This is the pen **which** I gave you yesterday.

Comment: You are most welcome.